# selectionStart and selectionEnd Returning Inaccurate Indices (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex

The requirement is for the user to be able to highlight separate parts of text.

For example if the textarea contained "01234567" the user should be able to highlight "1357" without highlighting "0246".

`selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are returning greater, random and inaccurate indexes of not more than 3 numbers off from the targeted index.

If `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` worked as expected the code below should work.

```
$("#P85_30DAY").attr("contenteditable","true");
$("#P85_30DAY").css("postition","absolute");
var selStartArray = [];
var selStartArrayMin = [];
var selEndArray = [];
var selEndArrayMax = [];
function ModifySelection () {            
            var textarea = document.getElementById("P85_30DAY");
            if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {                    
                if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) { 
                      var selTextStart = textarea.selectionStart;
                      var selTextEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;
                      var P8530DAY = $("#P85_30DAY").val();
                      var len =  P8530DAY.length;
                      var nextSelStartArray = "-1";
                      selStartArray.push(selTextStart);
                      selStartArrayMin.push(selTextStart);
                      selEndArray.push(selTextEnd);
                      selEndArrayMax.push(selTextEnd);
                      selStartArrayMin.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                      selEndArrayMax.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

text = "<span>" + textarea.value.substring (0, selStartArrayMin[0]);  
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {                                          
var indexVal = selStartArray.indexOf(i);                              
if (indexVal != -1){                                                  
text += "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'>" + textarea.value.substring  (selStartArray[indexVal], selEndArray[indexVal]) + "</span>" ;  
for (k = i+1; k < len; k++) {                                         
var indexValB = selStartArray.indexOf(k);                             
if (indexValB != -1){                                                
var nextSelStartArray = textarea.value.substring (selEndArray[indexValB - 1], selStartArray[indexValB]);
}}
if (nextSelStartArray != -1){                                        
text += nextSelStartArray;                                           
nextSelStartArray = "-1";
k = len;                                             
}}}
text += textarea.value.substring (selEndArrayMax[0]) + "</span>";      

                 $("#P85_30DAY").empty();                   
                 $(text).appendTo("#P85_30DAY");                     
                 $("#P85_60DAY").val("Length: " + "\n" + len + "\n" + "SelStart Array: " + "\n" + selStartArray + "\n" + "SelEnd Array: " + "\n" + selEndArray);                
                }
            }                       
        }
//document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onkeyup = ModifySelection;
document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onmouseup = ModifySelection;
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea name="p_t07" class="textarea" id="P85_30DAY" style="width: 587px; height: 600px; font-size: 130%; position: relative;" contenteditable="true" maxlength="4000" rows="1" cols="80" wrap="virtual"></textarea>

<!-- end snippet -->


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $("#P85_30DAY").attr("contenteditable","true");
$("#P85_30DAY").css("postition","absolute");
var selStartArray = [];
var selStartArrayMin = [];
var selEndArray = [];
var selEndArrayMax = [];
function ModifySelection () {            
            var textarea = document.getElementById("P85_30DAY");
            if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {                    
                if (textarea.selectionStart != textarea.selectionEnd) { 
                      var selTextStart = textarea.selectionStart;
                      var selTextEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;
                      var P8530DAY = $("#P85_30DAY").val();
                      var len =  P8530DAY.length;
                      var nextSelStartArray = "-1";
                      selStartArray.push(selTextStart);
                      selStartArrayMin.push(selTextStart);
                      selEndArray.push(selTextEnd);
                      selEndArrayMax.push(selTextEnd);
                      selStartArrayMin.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                      selEndArrayMax.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

text = "<span>" + textarea.value.substring (0, selStartArrayMin[0]);  
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {                                          
var indexVal = selStartArray.indexOf(i);                              
if (indexVal != -1){                                                  
text += "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'>" + textarea.value.substring  (selStartArray[indexVal], selEndArray[indexVal]) + "</span>" ;  
for (k = i+1; k < len; k++) {                                         
var indexValB = selStartArray.indexOf(k);                             
if (indexValB != -1){                                                
var nextSelStartArray = textarea.value.substring (selEndArray[indexValB - 1], selStartArray[indexValB]);
}}
if (nextSelStartArray != -1){                                        
text += nextSelStartArray;                                           
nextSelStartArray = "-1";
k = len;                                             
}}}
text += textarea.value.substring (selEndArrayMax[0]) + "</span>";      

                 $("#P85_30DAY").empty();                   
                 $(text).appendTo("#P85_30DAY");                     
                 $("#P85_60DAY").val("Length: " + "\n" + len + "\n" + "SelStart Array: " + "\n" + selStartArray + "\n" + "SelEnd Array: " + "\n" + selEndArray);                
                }
            }                       
        }
//document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onkeyup = ModifySelection;
document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onmouseup = ModifySelection;
```

This is the textarea that I am working with.

```
    <textarea name="p_t07" class="textarea" id="P85_30DAY" 
    style="width:587px;
    height: 600px; font-size: 130%; position: relative;" 
    contenteditable="true"
    maxlength="4000" rows="1" cols="80" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

When I replace the arrays with the correct `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` values, as below, the code works as expected. I believe the incorrect indexes returned are because of the spans being added. is there an alternative for `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` or a way to target the visible text and not the html?

```
$("#P85_30DAY").attr("contenteditable","true");
$("#P85_30DAY").css("postition","absolute");
var selStartArray = [1,3,5,7];
var selStartArrayMin = [1,3,5,7];
var selEndArray = [2,4,6,8];
var selEndArrayMax = [2,4,6,8];
function ModifySelection () {            
            var textarea = document.getElementById("P85_30DAY");
            if ('selectionStart' in textarea) {                    
                      var textTest = "01234567";
                      var selTextStart = textarea.selectionStart;
                      var selTextEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;
                      var len =  textTest.length;
                      var nextSelStartArray = "-1";
                      //selStartArray.push(selTextStart);
                      //selStartArrayMin.push(selTextStart);
                      //selEndArray.push(selTextEnd);
                      //selEndArrayMax.push(selTextEnd);
                      selStartArrayMin.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                      selEndArrayMax.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

text = "<span>" + textTest.substring (0, selStartArrayMin[0]);  
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {                                          
var indexVal = selStartArray.indexOf(i);                              
if (indexVal != -1){                                                  
text += "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'>" + textTest.substring  (selStartArray[indexVal], selEndArray[indexVal]) + "</span>" ;  
for (k = i+1; k < len; k++) {                                         
var indexValB = selStartArray.indexOf(k);                             
if (indexValB != -1){                                                
var nextSelStartArray = textTest.substring (selEndArray[indexValB - 1], selStartArray[indexValB]);
}
if (nextSelStartArray != -1){                                        
text += nextSelStartArray;                                           
nextSelStartArray = "-1";
k = len;                                            
}}}}
text += textTest.substring (selEndArrayMax[0]) + "</span>";      

                 $("#P85_30DAY").empty();                   
                 $(text).appendTo("#P85_30DAY");                     
                 $("#P85_60DAY").val("Length: " + "\n" + len + "\n" + "SelStart Array: " + "\n" + selStartArray + "\n" + "SelEnd Array: " + "\n" + selEndArray);                
                }                     
        };
//document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onkeyup = ModifySelection;
document.getElementById("P85_30DAY").onmouseup = ModifySelection;
```

This is what the textarea looks like with the correct `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` values.

```
    <textarea name="p_t07" class="textarea" id="P85_30DAY" style="width: 587px; 
 height: 600px; font-size: 130%; margin-top: -431px; margin-left: -1340px;
 position: relative;" contenteditable="true" maxlength="4000" rows="1" cols="80" 
 wrap="virtual"><span>0<span style="color: white; background-color: 
 blue;">1</span>2<span style="color: white; background-color: 
 blue;">3</span>4<span style="color: white; background-color: 
 blue;">5</span>6<span style="color: white; background-color: blue;">7</span>
 </span></textarea>
```

Comment: I have gotten it to work with hard coding multiple spans but to dynamically place those spans is the problem I am facing.

Comment: After the user has made the highlights, how do you plan to use them? Would you just display the content with multiple highlights to different users? Do you need to be able to work with the selections programmatically? Does it have to be in a textarea?

Comment: The highlights will be saved and then displayed later. Different users should be able to see the highlights. Barring highlights, textareas are the easiest to work with in Oracle Apex. If this cant work because of the selectionStart and selectionEnd bugs then multiple pages will have to be reworked and copious textareas will have to be changed to divs.